# Neo4j/Cypher Check for existing relationship on each node in linked list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher which returns a list of items created by a given user (which works fine):

```
MATCH (author:User)-[:ITEM_LIST*1..10]->item
WHERE author.username='1'
RETURN item
```

What I want now though, is to return a list of authored items, but to also know if a particular user has liked any of these items. I have tried the cypher below, but it doesn't work:

```
START user=node(1)
MATCH (author:User)-[:ITEM_LIST*1..10]->item<-[like?:LIKES]-user
WHERE author.username='1'
RETURN item, (like IS NOT NULL) as likes
```

I read the cypher above as returning all items, and optionally any likes between the items and the given user if they exist. Unfortunately the `?` makes no difference to the results, and it appears as though the `item<-[like?:LIKES]-user` is a requirement.

What would I need to do, to achieve the desired results?

EDIT:

I realised that I can do this by using `WITH item` and then checking for each optional relationship. Will this cause any performance issues? If so, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `WITH` syntax is similar to RETURN. It separates query parts explicitly, allowing you to declare which identifiers to carry over to the next part..

I'm Using it in many situations and I don't note any performance issue..

Also, you may create sample of the graph [here](http://console.neo4j.org/), so we can help..